# How do I position a tooltip relative to its trigger element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to display a JSON response (from an ajax call) in a tooltip. I would like to position the tooltip relative to its trigger element, an anchor, underneath it to its left. I will have many trigger elements on the same page. I thought of using something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // Do stuff
    success: function(response) {
        $(this).after("<div class='tooltip'>" + response.message + "</div>");
    }
});
```

This code doesn't solve my problem. It inserts the tooltip in the target element's container. I need the tooltip to float and be independent from the target element, sort of like the tooltips StackOverFlow displays when you vote on a post.

Any ideas how to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your tooltip independent of other elements, it should be a *direct child* of your `<body>` and with a high `z-index` CSS property.

If you try to drop the tooltip into the DOM anywhere else it could interfere with page layout.

Then just use `absolute` positioning based on the coordinates of the trigger element.

```
.tooltip {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: absolute;
}

var offset = $(trigger).offset();
offset.top += $(trigger).height();
$(tooltip).offset(offset);
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a direct child of the `body`, as long as it's positioned absolutely (and its parent isn't positioned relatively) it's taken out of the document flow completely.

Comment: @jack true, but it helps.  I normally have `div { position: relative }` as the default in all my stylesheets.

Comment: @Alnitak, thank you. But how do I inject the tooltip div? Do I still use after()?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery ui [`position()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) to place your tooltip with response relatively to particular element.